# Disable hard word wrapping in PhpStorm when formatting Smarty template

Tags: phpstorm, smarty, word-wrap

I can't disable hard word wrapping when formatting Smarty template file in PhpStorm 2018.3.

I have changed "Hard wrap at" setting to 500 in `Settings->Editor->Code Style->PHP` and to 1000 in `Settings->Editor->Code Style->HTML` but it wrap lines again when formatting.

Before formatting: 
[image: Smarty template before formatting]

After formatting:
[image: Smarty template after formatting]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjust the value of hard wrap at File | Settings | Editor | Code Style. Smarty doesn't have its own settings for Hard Wrap: it takes it from "General" config section.
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

Twig has it owns Code Style Settings:
[image: PhpStorm Settings]

Comment: But I'm using Smarty. I want to disable hard word wrapping in Smarty.

Comment: @nagiyevel can you show me your settings for Smarty?

Comment: @nagiyevel no worries :)